# How can I get html code from the web with vala(gtk)?

Tags: gtk, application-development, html, vala

How can I get a html code from some site(e.g. www.google.com) using vala(gtk)?

Comment: stackoverflow is a better site for programming questions.

Comment: Ok, I will ask this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: There was a discussion about this earlier in [Chat](http://chat.askubuntu.com/rooms/3/conversation/when-should-we-migrate). Conclusion: This is a perfectly acceptable question for AU. As [AU is for Ubuntu Users and Developers](http://askubuntu.com/about). Vala being a language for Gnome which is the default shipped desktop environment it is on topic. You're more than welcome to ask on StackOverflow but don't fret if you fear this is offtopic. If you feel differently please open a [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com) topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Vala GIO File open shown here http://live.gnome.org/Vala/GIOSamples

`var web_page = File.new_for_uri ("http://live.gnome.org/Vala");`

This is the standard method of grabbing files and web pages and you can use the uri syntax for a number of supported protocols such as ssh, ftp, etc.